# Understanding dependency injection in a mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The way dependency injection works is very mysterious to me. In this simple example:

```
public class LeagueController : BaseController
{  
    private readonly IDocumentSession documentSession;           

    public LeagueController(IDocumentSession documentSession) //where is this parameter coming from?
    {        
        this.documentSession = documentSession;
    }
```

What I don't get is where the initialized parameter is coming from to initialize  this.documentSession?   If I wanted to initialise another class in the constructor how would I do it?

Comment: Dependency injection usually goes hand in hand with IoC containers.  This is where your "mappings" are configured and the code will automatically handle the creation of these objects and the passing of the parameters.  To answer you specifically, we would need to know what IoC container you are using.  .NET Core has one built in, are you using .NET Core?

Comment: No, we're using MVC 5

Comment: The constructor for your class is called by the injector library; Simple Injector, Autofac or whatever you are using. Each class that you want to inject needs to be added to the configuration. Usually the configuration is located in the startup code; Global.asax or Startup.cs.

Comment: Thanks Bill, it's beginning to make sense. In my global.asax I have: var container = (IContainer) Bootstrapper.Startup();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));  So I guess it is doing the mapping on the second line, although I can't find the explicit code that does it.